# Excel won't open password-protected .ods file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, passwords, microsoft-excel-2013, libreoffice

I have a password-protected .ods file that was made in LibreOffice. I have since moved to using Microsoft Excel, and whenever I try to open the file I get the error message: "Cannot open: the file has been protected with a password and cannot be opened."

Is there a way to open this without reinstalling LibreOffice?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-OpenDocument-Spreadsheet-ods-format-and-the-Excel-xlsx-format-4311c54f-ee86-4197-bd2d-5ecc35deb138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no you cannot open password protected .ods files with [excel 2007 or 2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-OpenDocument-Spreadsheet-ods-format-and-the-Excel-xlsx-format-4311c54f-ee86-4197-bd2d-5ecc35deb138) as well as [2013 and 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-OpenDocument-Spreadsheet-ods-format-and-the-Excel-for-Windows-xlsx-format-3db958c8-e0ac-49a5-9965-2c2f8afbd960?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> When you save the file in .ods format and open it again in Excel,
>   protection without a password is supported. However, files with a
>   password-protected sheet cannot be saved or opened.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you open the spreadsheet in LibreOffice using the password, then save it in Office format (.xls or .xlsx, depending on the version of Excel you wish to use it in). The spreadsheet should then be accessible by your version of Excel, but bear in mind that the password will be removed by this action in some versions of Excel (2016, in my case) and will need to be re-done if protection is needed.